# How to include Streaming test jar in sbt build?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am trying to write unit test for Spark Streaming. For that I am trying to pull the test jar. But I am not able to pull the jar in my build with the following configuration:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.4.1"  % "test" classifier  % "tests"
```

I am getting error saying that:

> ';' expected but string literal found.

How to pull in the test-jar?

Comment: is your problem resolved.?

Comment: libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.4.1" artifacts(Artifact("spark-streaming","tests"))
your solution also works . Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an error in your dependency statement.

Please add as here.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.4.1" classifier "tests"
```

I have tested it and it works.